# Updating state - why creating a new copy of state when calling setState?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

React docs:

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards
>   may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were
>   immutable.

That's clear.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
   data: []
  }
```

the following I understand

```
  updateState(event) {
   const {name, value} = event.target;
   let user = this.state.user; // this is a reference, not a copy...
   user[name] = value; // 
   return this.setState({user}); // so this could replace the previous mutation
  }
```

this following I don't understand

```
  updateState(event) {
  const {name, value} = event.target;
  let user = {...this.state.user, [name]: value};
  this.setState({user});
  }
```

I understand (as in previous example), that I should not either only:

1. mutate state directly without calling setState; or
2. mutate it and then use setState afterwards.

However, why can't I just (without direct mutation) call setState *without* creating a new copy of state (no spread operator/`Object.assign`)? What would be wrong with the following:

```
  getData = () => {
   axios.get("example.com") ...
    this.setState({
     data:response.data
    })
  }
```

Why should it be:

```
  getData = () => {
   axios.get("example.com") ...
    this.setState({
     data:[...data, response.data]
    })
  } 

 render (){ 
  ...
 }  
}
```

Comment: Because in your example you want to add the response data to the end of the array, rather than replace the array with it? They're not equivalent at all, that's separate from the issue of mutation.

Comment: You do it because you need to work only on new instances of data. those new instance are created based on the previous instance combined with the new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What would be wrong with the following:*

```
this.setState({
   data: response.data,
});
```

Absolutely nothing, unless you don't want to replace the contents of `this.state.data` with `response.data`.

*Why should it be:*

```
this.setState({
   data: [...data, response.data],
});
```

Because with spread you are not loosing the contents of `this.state.data` - you are basically pushing new response into the `data` array.

**Note**: You should use callback inside `setState` to get access to current `data` from `this.state`.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
   data: [...prevState.data, response.data],
}));
```

Comment: ahh okay I get it now. Creating a copy of the state is only for cases where I want to add not replace something to an array or object. Thank you!!

Comment: @javascripting: Just keep in mind to avoid mutating functions if it's related with state in React. You dont really want to use e.g. `push` or `splice` when operating directly on state. You have to use some other function that doesnt mutate and returns new instance, like `slice`, `concat` or spread syntax.

Comment: @javascripting Or basically create a deep copy first, then you are able to use mutating functions on that copy without a risk of mutating the state directly.

Comment: Also, I have one more question. Using spead operator/Object.assign or concat etc only works if its not a deeper nested state. For example: var state = {
      _2ndLevel: {
        arr: []
      }
    }  --> in this case, the nested object still would be referenced so I would mutate state eventually directly. What would be good to do here (without using any immutability library helpers)? Thanks!!

Comment: I would think the best solution is just not to have deeply nested data?!

Comment: @javascripting In case of deep state you just have to go deeper ;) Destructure whole state until you get to the specified part of it. Anyways yeah, it's just better to keep the state as flat as it's possible.