# this.setState not updating initial empty state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Initially I have an empty state called `hours`. I want to update that state with an array that I put together later on called `all_hours`. When I do `this.state.hours = all_hours`, the state gets updated. However, when I do `this.setState({hours:all_hours})` it doesn't get updated.

```
class DevicesInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hours: []
    };
  }
 

 componentDidMount() {
     // some api calls 
     all_hours = ["12:00 am", "1:00 am", "2:00 am", ... "12:00 pm"];
     this.state.hours = all_hours // correct array printed
     this.setState({hours:all_hours}) // empty array printed
}
```

Comment: How do you know it works/doesn't work? Because in terms of what's shown on the screen, the first one that you say "works" very much does *not* work...

Comment: Where in your component are you calling `this.setState()` ?

Comment: @redouglas Apologies for the lack of details. I updated the original post with where I called it (in `componentDidMount()`).

Comment: if you're simply `console.log`ing to check right after the `setState` call, that will not show you the updated state since it updates asynchronously

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating state - why creating a new copy of state when calling setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901446/updating-state-why-creating-a-new-copy-of-state-when-calling-setstate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a quick run in code sandbox and it seems to be working fine, can you provide extra information so I can guide you better.

here is the link to example on code sandbox for you to check

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-haibt-b6pw4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks for this! it seems like my issue was was with not understanding that `console.log`ing does not show me the updated state when it actually does update it.

Comment: Glad I could of any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Write it this way:

```
class DevicesInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hours: []
    };
  }
 all_hours = ["12:00 am", "1:00 am", "2:00 am", ... "12:00 pm"];

componentDidMount() {
    //this.state.hours = this.all_hours ;
    this.setState({hours: [...this.all_hours]}) ;
  }
}
```